# Как преобразовать форматированные даты в цифры (3.12M)

Tags: c#

Допустим строка 3,12К. Я хочу преобразовать его в норм число. Как я вижу решение. Пройтись по списку словаря, найти совпадение - заменить. Есть ли более простое решение. Может я велосипед строю тут?

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dic.Add("K", 1000);
dic.Add("M", 1000000);
```

Comment: Можно и так. А что вас смущает в вашем варианте?

Comment: @Kromster хочу более элегантное решение

Comment: А какое решение по-вашему будет более элегантным и почему? В языке c# готовых конструкций нет, про такие библиотеки я не слышал, но допустим они есть - там же внутри будет такой же код, как у вас, не цепи же Маркова и не нейросетки же, верно?

Comment: готового такого ничего нет во фреймворке, придется либо библиотеку искать, либо самому написать, благо это 5-10 строчек кода всего то